# Jasper Report has no pages (invalid page index range)

Tags: java

```
        reportParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();       

        List<IdentificadorTO> parametros = prettyprintService.getCartaoCorrenteImpressao(cartao);

        for (IdentificadorTO parametro : parametros) 
        {
            if (!parametro.getConteudo().isEmpty()) {               
                reportParams.put(parametro.getIdentificador().toString(), parametro.getConteudo().toString());
            }
        } 

        String jasperLocation = prettyprintService.getModeloRealCartao(id);
        File reportFile = new File(ServletActionContext.getServletContext()
                .getRealPath(jasperLocation));

        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(reportFile);         
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, reportParams);
    } 
    catch (JRRuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (JRException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return ERROR;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
```

I got a message which gives me

`JRException: invalid page index range`

The report parameters are load directly via database, I don't need a datasource. All I got it is just a message (invalid page index range) from my applet console.

Comment: could this problem be caused by a possible null reportParams?

Comment: I have fixed it by myself. I have just added a third parameter - an empty datasource object.